# Git - why do I get Conflicts between develop and master branches

Tags: git

I have two branches : `master` branch and `develop`.

Until now, `develop` and `master` were pretty much the same.
From now on, I want to push all the `hotfixes` into `master` and new features into `develop`, but I also need to make sure that`develop` has all the fixes from `master`.

What I usually do :

**For a fix**:
From `master` branch : `git checkout -b fix/my-fix`.
When I'm done with the development, I do a `git push origin/my-fix` then`my-fix` is merged into `master` using Gitlab Merge Request.

**For new feature 1** :
From my `master` branch, I've made : `git checkout -b feature/new-feature-1` and then `new-feature` is pushed into `develop` after some time.
Before pushing into `develop`, I've made a `git rebase master` (before a `git pull origin master` on `master` branch) to make sure that `develop` will get `master` changes.

**For new feature 2** :
From my `develop` branch, I've made : `git checkout -b feature/new-feature-2` and then `new-feature-2` is pushed into `develop` after some time. Once again, I used `git rebase master` before pushing into develop.

Now, I've pushed a `fix2` into master and when I go to my `develop` branch and do a `git rebase master`, I have many conflicts and I don't know why.
If I often use `git rebase master` on `develop`, how can this happen?
Am I doing something wrong ?
I also get sometimes a message saying that my  branch

After a `git rebase master` this is the message I get :

```
rebase in progress; onto 23ddfcc1
You are currently rebasing branch 'develop' on '23ddfcc1'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)
```

And the graph of `develop` gives :

```
*   commit 9fc59e3a5b1de6d93c2f9560ba0a758fb507b672 (HEAD -> develop)
|\  Merge: b620adef 23ddfcc1
| | Author: 
| | Date:   Wed Sep 30 23:38:51 2020 +0200
| |
| |     Merge branch 'master' of '' into develop
| |
| *   commit 23ddfcc15ea7a7ad9d5f8c45d386e78c9b6bbf8c (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
| |\  Merge: 572e5a9d 1833bf1f
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Wed Sep 30 23:13:08 2020 +0200
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'fix/FIX-1/some-name' into 'master'
| | |
| | |     
| | |
| | |     See merge request XX!322
| | |
| | * commit 1833bf1f84433ecf4fe4a1f707b891ed6c3ea0b0 (origin/fix/FIX-2/some-error, fix/FIX-2/some-error)
| |/  Author: 
| |   Date:   Wed Sep 30 14:04:56 2020 +0200
| |
| |      
| |
* |   commit b620adef2ec7d2cce5d9e75acea51554f3735f9f (origin/develop)
|\ \  Merge: 11e48497 dc8d2433
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Wed Sep 30 16:37:39 2020 +0200
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'develop'  into develop
| | |
| * |   commit dc8d2433d80385e011845a76b6536732c824dacc
| |\ \  Merge: db14ba4d dd0c8698
| | | | Author: 
| | | | Date:   Wed Sep 30 16:29:55 2020 +0200
| | | |
| | | |     Merge branch 'feature/FEATURE1/contact-form' into 'develop'
| | | |
| | | |   
| | | |
| | | |     See merge request !318
| | | |
| | * | commit dd0c8698c84e67adaed4dd1d477e6f9fb4e1bbf8 (origin/feature/FEATURE1/contact-form, feature/FEATURE1/contact-form)
| | | | 
| | | | Date:   Mon Sep 28 12:04:17 2020 +0200
```

Comment: You keep saying “push into”. Git uses the term “push” in a specific way, but it cannot be followed by “into”. Do you actually mean “merge”? If you do, do you always mean a true merge with a merge commit, or a fake GitHub “merge” that is actually a rebase or squash? I think from your graph that you usually mean true merge but it’s important to be clear.

Comment: hi @matt, yes I mean true merge.

Comment: Ok, well, I can already suggest that your life would be a lot better if the branch you start on when you make a new branch is the branch you will merge the new branch into. Checking out master, making a new branch, then checking out develop and merging that new branch, that is a recipe for difficulties because of what a merge is.

Comment: yes, I agree. but it was just for feature1. When I realized that I started from the wrong branch, it was too late. but then, for feature2, I started from develop for develop.

Comment: OK so what's the question exactly? Is it just that you're surprised that a rebase can result in conflicts?

Comment: I've got two questions : is it the right thing to do to use "git rebase master" on my "develop" branch to get "master" changes ? And the second question is related to the conflicts. When I use "git rebase master", the conflicts happens on file that only exists in develop. It seems like there is a conflict between the current version and a previous version from develop. Since I'm rebasing with master, I don't understand why I do get conflicts on files that do not exist on master

Comment: @sewey do you get the same conflicts if you merge (no fast forward) instead of rebasing?

Comment: No, with a merge, everything is fine. I only get the changes from master what I don't have in develop.

Comment: @evolutionxbox any idea what I don't get the same results with git merge and git rebase? What happens is that I need to resolve conflicts twice. but each time, it involves files that don't exist in master, but in a previous version of develop.

Comment: I'm still confused about what the question is. You say "When I use "git rebase master", the conflicts happens on file that only exists in develop". So is the question, you don't understand how a conflict can involve a file that exists in just one branch in a rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still confused about what the question is, but I *think* it is: "How can there be a conflict during rebase for a file that exists only in the branch we are rebasing?" So I will answer that.

---

What is a rebase? It is basically a repeated cherry-pick.

What is a cherry-pick? It is a kind of merge. It's a merge by application of a patch, which is the expression of a diff.

Consider the following situation:

```
A - B - C (master)
    |
    X - Y (feature)
```

Let's say you are on feature and you say `git rebase master`. What does that mean?

The goal here is to "move" X and Y onto C. You can't really "move" a commit, though; we are actually going to make new commits X' and Y' that effectively replicate the kind of thing X and Y do. How is that possible?

Well, start with the *parent* of X, which is B. There is some *difference* between B and X, i.e. you have *do something* to B to get from B to X. Well, do that same "something" to C, and that will give us X'.

Okay, so for simplicity let's say there is just one file in this repo, *A.txt*. And it is present in commit B. And let's say X appends a line to *A.txt*. But let's say C deletes *A.txt*!

So from the point of view of the endpoints, *A.txt* exists only in `feature`, as you have put it. But from the point of view of the *merge*, i.e. the attempt to "replay" the change B->X as a change C->X', it is *not clear how to proceed*. C has no *A.txt*; meanwhile, X *presupposes* the existence of *A.txt*, which it edits.

That's a conflict.

I will now enact that scenario, creating the graph that I drew above, and then I will rebase to show you the conflict.

```
$ git init
$ echo howdy > A.txt
$ git add A.txt
$ git commit -m"A"
$ echo howdy >> A.txt
$ git commit -a -m"B"
$ git branch feature # but don't get on it yet
$ git rm A.txt
$ git commit -a -m"C"
$ ls # crickets... ok, time for the branch
$ git checkout feature
$ ls
A.txt
$ echo yoho >> A.txt
$ git commit -a -m"X"
$ echo yoho >> A.txt
$ git commit -a -m"Y"
$ cat A.txt
howdy
howdy
yoho
yoho
$ git log --oneline
3308220 (HEAD -> feature) Y
f829812 X
ede9af5 B
a2a98f2 A
$ git log --oneline master
2dfe0fb (master) C
ede9af5 B
a2a98f2 A
```

Very well, we're ready for our rebase!

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: X
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   A.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): A.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in X. 
 Version X of A.txt left in tree.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 X
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

So you see, we rebased and got a conflict on a file that is "in" just one branch. There are other ways for that to happen but that shows that the thing is possible, indeed quite easy.

And now, I will *resolve* the conflict:

```
$ git add A.txt
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: X
Applying: Y
$ git log --oneline
d621b67 (HEAD -> feature) Y
0b7c870 X
2dfe0fb (master) C
ede9af5 B
a2a98f2 A
```

And so the rebase ends in good order. In closing, look closely at the SHA of X and Y before and after the rebase, and you will see that X and Y after the rebase are indeed different commits from X and Y before the rebase. The "old" X and Y still exist, but as nothing now points to them, they will in all likelihood eventually be cleaned up.

---

So what's the lesson here? In order to rebase feature onto master, we start with the commit *before* feature gets going. We must then take account of *the whole history of master after that point*, and at the same time, *the history from that point to the first commit of feature*. If we cannot resolve those two histories as an automatic merge, that's a conflict and we need help from the user. And so on, through every commit of feature.